# Cant resolve the facebook log out

Tags: iphone, facebook

I am using the facebook sdk to login to an app in iphone. Once the app is launched and logged in with a facebook account, count proceed further. Then I stop the simulator and run the app again to log out, but I couldn't log out. I went to the login page and pressed login and then only could log out. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You provide this method when user clicks on logout and remove all keys stored in userdefault for facebook

```
- (void)fbDidLogout
{
  NSLog(@"Logged out of facebook");
  NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
  NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
  for (cookie in [storage cookies])
  {
   NSString* domainName = [cookie domain];
   NSRange domainRange = [domainName rangeOfString:@"facebook"];
   if(domainRange.length > 0)
   {
       [storage deleteCookie:cookie];
   }
  }
}
```